# Wordpress: 403 error after changing domain name

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I have a wordpress instance (Version 3.5.1) installed on a third party webhoster (www.hoststar.ch). The installation on the server is in a subdirectory /test/wordpress. When I installed the wordpress instance, I gave the URL http://test.example.com as URL. Now I want to change the URL into http://www.newexample.com. I set the new URL to point to the same subdirectory on the server as the old URL. But when I open the new URL, the server gives me an 403 error, telling me:

> "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

I figured out that when I change the entry "RewriteEngine On" to "RewriteEngine Off" in the .htaccess file (the one of the wordpress subdirectory, not the one in the root directory), it works with the new URL. However, the pretty permalinks do not work anymore, as the RewriteEngine is switched off.

Does somebody have an idea why I cannot access the wordpress instance with the new URL when the RewriteEngine is set to On?

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are the file permissions of the .htaccess?

Comment: The filepermissions are 666.

Comment: Often this will fix itself if you turn permalinks off and on again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and answers. In the end it was a problem with the mod_rewrite modul on the server. The hosting company had to activate the mod_rewrite for the new domain name in order to make it work. It was only activated for the old domain name.

Cheers Lukas